# How I can add column before another column in dbforge?

Tags: codeigniter, dbforge

I want to add column that name 'accept_loc', type 'VARCHAR' to 3 database tables (use dbforge library from codeigniter) Assum they are named t1,t2,t3.

**t1 structure:**

- id
- bla_bla
- pick_up_loc
- ....

**t2 structure:**

- id
- pick_up_loc
- ....

**t3 structure:**

- id
- bla_bla
- pick_up_loc
- ....

if I used this code below in my migration up function:

```
$fields = array(
        'accept_lat' => array(
            'accept_loc' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '50',
            'after' => 'id',
        ),
    );
$this->dbforge->add_column('t1',$fields);
$this->dbforge->add_column('t2',$fields);
$this->dbforge->add_column('t3',$fields);
```

result:

**t1 structure:**

- id
- accept_loc
- bla_bla
- pick_up_loc
- ....

**t2 structure:**

- id
- accept_loc
- pick_up_loc
- ....

**t3 structure:**

- id
- accept_loc
- bla_bla
- pick_up_loc
- ....

it's not a good looking structure. How can I add column before 'pick_up_loc' to all of them (n database tables).

Answer (score 1):

Please try to put the after in uppercase, that is 'AFTER', there was a bug in that `after` key and mentioned got fixed [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2703).

```
    $fields = array(
        'accept_lat' => array(
            'accept_loc' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '50',
            'AFTER' => 'id'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The third argument in add_column() is $after_field. So you can't add the column **before** another column but you can do this:

```
$this->dbforge->add_column('t1', $fields, 'bla_bla');
$this->dbforge->add_column('t2', $fields, 'id');
$this->dbforge->add_column('t3', $fields, 'bla_bla');
```

Also, you seem to be naming the field 'accept_lat' and then using 'accept_loc' instead of the 'type' element which is confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but to clarify your code, on t1 for example, should look like this:

```
 $fields = array(
            'accept_lat' => array('type' => 'TEXT')
);
    $this->dbforge->add_column('t1', $fields, 'id');
```

So accept_lat will be added after the id column in table t1.